# show default value for the ngbTypeahead

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I want to set the default value or say initially any value in the `ngbTypeahead` input field.

abc.component.html

```
<input id="typeahead-basic" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="typeAheadProduct"
    style="width:140px" [resultFormatter]="resultFormatterProduct"
    [inputFormatter]="inputFormatterProduct" (selectItem)="Selected($event)"
    [ngbTypeahead]="searchProduct" placeholder="Start typing 2-3 letters"/>
```

Any kind of information would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see `formControlName="typeAheadProduct"`. That means you bind the value of the form control with name `typeAheadProduct` to the typeahead. You can set the value of this control when it it initialized and the typeahead will use this value as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using template-driven forms, this worked for me:

```
this.myForm.controls["location"].setValue(location);
```

Where `location` is the object/class that the NgbTypeAhead is searching, and which the formatter uses to set the label using the `.name` property, as shown below:

```
public formatter = (location: Location) => location.name;
```